# SyntaxError when trying to launch Blender 2.78 with Python 3.6

Tags: python

i just did a fresh install of Blender 2.78 (32 bits) on windows 10, i also have only one version of Python 3.6 (32 bits) installed and i can't launch Blender, i get this error message :

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\os.py", line 652, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\_collections_abc.py", line 64
    async def _ag(): yield
                ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function
```

This is my PATH variable :

```
Path= ... C:\Python36\;C:\Python36\Scripts
```

and my Pythonpath variable :

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Python36\Lib
```