# I can't run Blender when I reboot computer

Tags: python, system

I have a problem like below so I delete system variable and succeed to run.

Problem: [SyntaxError when trying to launch Blender 2.78 with Python 3.6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71917/syntaxerror-when-trying-to-launch-blender-2-78-with-python-3-6)

But It doesn't run when I reboot computer and problem is occured which solved before. To run blender I have to launch it again in my computer then blender is running without problem

How can I solve this

Comment: Blender has a bundled Python installation built into it, it doesn't need an external one. Unless you specifically need it, I'd recommend uninstalling it